# C#-Lua UDP incompatibility (no message received)

Tags: c#, lua, udp, luasocket

My problem:
A UDP message sent by a C# application (.NET 4.6.1) is not showing up in a Lua client (LOVE 0.9.2 with bundled LuaSocket). 
The send code is hilariously simple:

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(port);
listener.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, "client_ip", 1234);
```

The receive code is relatively simple as well:

```
local socket = require("socket")
local address,port = "server_ip",1234
local udp = socket.udp()
udp:settimeout(0)
udp:setpeername(address,port)
local data,msg_ip,port_nil

function love.update(dt)
    repeat
        data,msg_ip,port_nil = udp:receive()
        if data then
            print(data)
        elseif msg_ip~="timeout" then
            print(msg_ip)
        end
    until not data
end
```

Comment: Don't you need `udp:setsockname('*',port)` to bind the receive socket for listening?  Setting the peer is setting where this socket would send to, not where it listens.  You're on an ephemeral port.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Worked like a charm, completely fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael said, the problem was not, in fact, an incompatibility in the UDP implementations. I forgot to include `udp:setsockname('*',port)` in my client Lua code, which is a completely different and much easier problem. Unless there are complaints, I will leave the mistitled question up in the hopes of helping out any other misguided souls.